# Need some help understanding the factorised posterior in semi-supervised generative modelling

Tags: posterior, autoencoders, variational-bayes, semi-supervised-learning

I am having a bit of trouble with the derivation in [Kingma's semi-supervised generative modelling paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5352-semi-supervised-learning-with-deep-generative-models) for the M2-model.

The M2 model assumes a probabilistic model where the data $x$ is generated by hidden latents $z$ in addition to class variables $y$, which can also be modelled as latents when unobserved in the semi-supervised case.

The approximate posterior takes the form $q(z, y|x)$ which one assumes to be factorised such that $q(z, y|x)=q(z|x)q(y|x)$. So far so good.

However, Equation (4) of the paper when specifying the variational family of each variable has:

- $q(z|x,y) = \mathcal{N}(z|\mu_x(x,y),\text{diag}\left(\sigma_x(x,y)\right)$

  - $q(y|x) = \text{Cat}\left(y|\pi_x(x)\right)$

This makes sense as by applying product rule, $q(z, y|x)=q(z|x,y)q(y|x)$.

In Algorithm 2 of the paper, $q(y|x)$ is used to get an estimate of $y_i$ in the unlabelled case $x_i$ and then used to get $q(z_i|x_i,y_i)$.

In various implementations I have found on the internet: e.g. [here](https://github.com/Response777/Semi-supervised-VAE/blob/master/ssl_m2_v2.ipynb) and [here](https://github.com/wohlert/semi-supervised-pytorch/blob/master/semi-supervised/models/dgm.py) - $x$ and $y$ are both used to get $z$ as per $q(z|x,y)$.

My main question is such: why can one assume a factorised posterior in the form $q(z, y|x)=q(z|x)q(y|x)$ yet implement it as $q(z, y|x)=q(z|x,y)q(y|x)$? The latent space of $q(z|x)$ and $q(z|x, y)$ will be vastly different as the former is a vanilla VAE where one would expect clustering based on digit class whilst the latter is a [conditional latent space](https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/12/17/conditional-vae/).

1. Is the factorised statement correct because we use two separate neural networks to encode $z$ and $y$?
2. Can we assume $q(z|x, y) \rightarrow q(z|x)$ in Kingma's formulation as he effectively marginalises $y$ in the unlabelled case by performing $\sum_y q(y|x)\mathcal{L}(x,y)$? If so, how does this affect using a Gumbel-Softmax where we have access to a sample of $y$ and do not need to marginalise.

In other work e.g. [Flexible Fairness by Disentanglement](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/creager19a/creager19a.pdf), the factorised posterior $q(z,b|x)=q(z|x)q(b|x)$ is consistent with the implementation; one encoder $q(z|x)$ and separate encoder $q(b|x)$.

My gut feeling is that using $q(z|x,y)$ is due to the semi-supervised aspect of the work..but I'm not so sure.

Thank you for any help - this may be trivial but I am trying to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: i am 99% sure $q(z,y|x) = q(z|x)q(y|x)$ is a typo, and $q(z,y|x) = q(z|x,y)q(y|x)$ was meant.

Comment: Yeah - that's certainly possible and probably the most likely answer. I guess I was just wondering if there was something more subtle to understand that would be obvious once explained.